# Xmppframework IOS messages not received when app is in background

Tags: ios, message, xmppframework

I am working on chat based application using XMPPFramework and Open fire everything's good and working fine.

Am facing an problem,When someone send a message, Messages are not receiving at client end when app is in background.

How do i achieve it, without using VoIP.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1)You need to enable archiving on the server.
2)Follow  [link](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html)  to get the messages.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Apple Push Notification Services to achieve this functionality.

Visit following link -
[send push notification to ios for chat to offline user, openfire xmpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097020/send-push-notification-to-ios-for-chat-to-offline-user-openfire-xmpp)